# "Go on, I dare you!" - Does a similar phrase or concept exist in German?

Tags: word-usage

My brother in law and I were having a discussion around 'dare' vs. 'etw. wagen'. I had said something along the lines of "ich wage dich etw. zu machen" and he intimated that it doesn't really work in German. Is there a viable alternative?

Comment: https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=i+dare+you

Comment: "traust di nie!" (in Austria) from "sich (ge)trauen"

Answer (score 10):

You could say something like "komm schon, trau dich".

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer a little bit. It is correct, but it is a little bit short...

Comment: What would help is a literal translation, along with an explanation of why it means the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

Your brother is right - "to dare" has (at least) two different translations in German that each cannot be replaced by the other:

**"Ich wage etwas (zu tun)"** only works if *I*, the subject, am the one who is challenged to do something, i.e. **"I dare to do something"**.

On the other hand, if I say **"I dare *you* to do something"**, the challenge goes to *you*, the object. In this case, the correct translation is **"Ich fordere dich heraus, etwas zu tun"**.

(**"Ich wage dich, etwas zu tun"** is plain wrong and **"Ich fordere heraus, etwas zu tun"** is a bit weird and has a completely different meaning anyways)

It's surely possible to translate **"Go on, I dare you"** very literally by **"Mach weiter, ich fordere dich dazu heraus"**, and this would be a correct German sentence. However, it does sound very unnatural (it doesn't really capture the threatening undertone of the English counterpart).

Laurin's **"[Komm schon / Na los], trau dich (doch)!"** (~**"Come on, dare to do it!"**) is a much closer alternative.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers I also know the phrase *Mach nur so weiter (du wirst schon sehen, was Du davon hast)...* as a threat for consequences if you actually dare to go on.

Answer (score 1):

The German word *wagen* is no complete equivalent of *to dare*. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dare) lists several meanings. Not all can be translated by means of *wagen*:

- (auxiliary verb) *to be sufficiently courageous to*

  > *"no one dared say a word"*: "niemand wagte es ein Wort zu sagen"
- (intransitive verb) *to have sufficient courage*

  > *"try it if you dare"*: *"Versuchs nur, wenn du es wagst!"* (: *"... wenn du dich traust!"*)
- (transitive verb)

  - *to challenge to perform an action especially as a proof of courage* or *to confront boldly*

    > - *"dared him to jump"*:  **No direct translation!** (alternative: *zu etw. herausfordern*)
    > - *"dared the anger of his family"*: **No direct translation!** (alternative: *riskieren*)
  - *to have the courage to contend against, venture, or try*

    > *"the actress dared a new interpretation of the classic role"*: *"Die Darstellerin wagte eine Neuinterpration der klassischen Rolle"*

**P.S.:** I forgot to propose an alternative. "Mach schon! Du traust dich doch eh nicht!" is a provocative way to express a challenge.

Comment: +1 For the clear exposition. *Ich wette, du traust dich nicht* + *zu* + infinitive seems to convey the aspect of challenge well.

Comment: Zu meiner Schulzeit wurde das *Ich wette, du traust dich nicht* mit einem einzigen Wort ausgedrückt: **Hemmung!**